# Seeking Guidance on Accessing Test Annotations in Azure DevOps Using 'azure-devops-node-api'

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, playwright

I am currently working on a project where we utilize test annotations by adding our team name through a fixture, as demonstrated in the code snippet below:

```
function setTeam(team: Team) {
  const annotations = base.info().annotations;
  const teamAnnotation = annotations.find((a) => a.type === 'team');

  if (teamAnnotation) {
    teamAnnotation.description = team;
  } else {
    annotations.push({
      type: 'team',
      description: team,
    });
  }
}
```

These annotations are then incorporated into the JUnit test reporter, which presents them as properties in the test-results.xml file:

```xml
<testcase name="Sample Tests" classname="adminCenter/sample.spec.ts" time="23.24">
  <properties>
    <property name="team" value="MyTeam"></property>
  </properties>
</testcase>
```

To streamline our workflow, we are using the 'azure-devops-node-api' package to access build information, test runs, and test results in Azure DevOps. The code snippet below outlines our approach:

```
// ... (previous code)

// Get a reference to the BuildApi
const buildApi = await webApi.getBuildApi();
// Get a reference to the TestApi
const testApi = await webApi.getTestApi();

// Get all builds for the specified build definition
const builds = await buildApi.getBuilds(
  projectName,
  [buildDefinitionId]
);

console.log('Number of builds fetched: ', builds?.length);

// Iterate through the builds
for (const build of builds) {
  console.log('[##section] Getting Build Details for build: ', build.id);

  // ... (previous code)

  // Iterate through the test runs and print their details
  for (const testRun of testRuns) {
    console.log('[##section] Getting Test Runs for build: ', build.id);

    // ... (previous code)

    // Get all test cases for the test run
    const testCases = await testApi.getTestResults(projectId, testRun.id, ResultDetails.SubResults);

    // Iterate through the test cases
    for (const testCase of testCases) {
      testCaseList.push({
        // ... (previous code)
        testOwner: 'team', // This should be assigned through customFields,
                           // and all properties in test-results.xml should be available as customFields.
        // ... (previous code)
      });
    }
  }
}

// ... (rest of the code)
```

However, we are facing a challenge in accessing the test annotations we publish in the test results using the 'azure-devops-node-api' or any other npm package. We would greatly appreciate guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you publish the test annotations as attachments of the test results? If so, maybe you can use [TestResultsApi](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api/blob/master/api/TestResultsApi.ts). If not, would you please let me know how did you publish the test annotations in the test results?